# Got translit names via xmlReader from Google Maps

Tags: api, google-maps, translate

Request string is like:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=59.711014,30.565287&output=xml&oe=utf8&sensor=false&gl=ru&key=67ad03c0-ed77-4851-b4a5-3da1fbc0e26f

Via browser it's ok. (Тверская)

Via xmlReader it's (Tverskaya) and I feel sad.

How can I change it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you're trying to use the v2 geocoder as Broady mentioned.

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&sensor=false&language=ru&address=59.711014,30.565287`

Note that for V3, lang is now language and address is now latlng.
That get your language filter working again. 
Happy Trails.
b

Comment: Still no go. - "Moskovskoye shosse, Saint Petersburg, Russia" instead of "Московское ш., Санкт-Петербург, Россия". Request string is: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?&sensor=false&lang=ru&address=59.798271,30.404396". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is the old Maps API Geocoder. Use the new interface here:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=59.711014,30.565287&language=ru

Second, it's possible we don't have a translation in Russian for that address. Map data updates were recently rolled out to many countries, so it's possible this is the reason for the change in response.

Comment: we don't have a translation in Russian for that address.

Comment: Wait - via browser it's on russian.